# C CUDA send struct array to host from device

Tags: c, struct, cuda

I have this structure

```
struct Data {
    int x
    int y;
    float z;
};
```

I sent it without problems to kernel

```
__global__ void calculate(Data *d_data) {
    d_data[myCounter].x = 1;
    d_data[myCounter].y = 1;
    d_data[myCounter].z = 1.0;
}

#DEFINE MAX_SIZE 100

int main() {
  Data * data = (Data *)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(Data));
  Data *d_data;

  const int DATA_BYTES = MAX_SIZE * sizeof(Data);
  int elements = 20;

  cudaError_t cudaStatus;

  cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, DATA_BYTES);
  if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
  }

  cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, DATA_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
  }

  calculate << < 1, elements >> > (d_data);

  cudaMemcpy(data, d_data, DATA_BYTES, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
  }

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  for (i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    printf("%2d %2.1f %s\n", d_data[i].x, d_data[i].y, 
    d_data[i].z);    // this prints nothing
  }
  cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();

}
```

When I tested struct array inside kernel function calculate it printed right results but when I try to send data from device to host using cudaMemcpy program crashes with no errros and prints nothing, how I can transfer this struct array from device?

Comment: Could you provide some details on the value of `myCounter` in the code above ? Also, could you provide the compilation scheme you are using for this code ? Indeed, structure alignment may vary. Finally, you want to check for errors when doing `cudaDeviceSynchronize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code you have shown.

1. You are missing a semicolon in your struct definition.
2. No definition is provided in the kernel code for the variable `myCounter`
3. No definition is provided for the variable `i` in `main`
4. You are attempting to print from the device variable `d_data` instead of the host variable `data`.  This is illegal in CUDA.  After copying to the host variable `data`, print from there.
5. You are using incorrect `printf` format specifiers.  The data types in your struct are an `int`, an `int` and a `float`.  You were using `%2d %2.1f %s` which would match an `int`, a `float`, and a string variable (null-terminated array of characters), but is incorrect for your struct.

The following code has the above issues addressed and seems to run correctly for me:

```
$ cat t430.cu
#include <stdio.h>

struct Data {
    int x;  // was missing semicolon
    int y;
    float z;
};

__global__ void calculate(Data *d_data) {
    int myCounter = threadIdx.x;  // this line was missing
    d_data[myCounter].x = 1;
    d_data[myCounter].y = 1;
    d_data[myCounter].z = 1.0;
}

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main() {
  Data * data = (Data *)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(Data));
  Data *d_data;
  int i;   // this line was missing
  const int DATA_BYTES = MAX_SIZE * sizeof(Data);
  int elements = 20;

  cudaError_t cudaStatus;

  cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_data, DATA_BYTES);
  if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!");
  }

  cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, DATA_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
  }

  calculate << < 1, elements >> > (d_data);

  cudaMemcpy(data, d_data, DATA_BYTES, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!");
  }

  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  for (i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    printf("%2d %2d %2.1f\n", data[i].x, data[i].y,
    data[i].z);    // this was trying to print from d_data
  }
  cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();

}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_61 -o t430 t430.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t430
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
 1  1 1.0
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add this macro to your code

```
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(call)                                               
do {                                                                  
    cudaError_t err = call;                                           
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.", 
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err) );       
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                          
    }                                                                
} while (0)
```

then:

```
CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(data, d_data, DATA_BYTES, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

btw, your `myCounter` seems not right. Could you provide some details on the value of myCounter in the code above?

Comment: You should add an error check on cudaDeviceSynchronize.